# Combining lists of a factors with multiplicity

Tags: list-manipulation, number-theory

I want to combine factorizations of integers (in the form output by `FactorInteger`, that is a list of factors with multiplicities) into the factorization of the product (without additional factorization effort, by adding the multiplicities). I have something working (I believe):

```
(*" Merge two non-empy ordered lists of factors with multiplicity, forming the list for product "*)
MergeF[a_, b_] := Block[{
  p = First[First[a]], n = Last[First[a]], u = Drop[a, 1], 
  q = First[First[b]], m = Last[First[b]], v = Drop[b, 1]}, 
  If[p < q, Prepend[If[u != {}, MergeF[u, b], b], {p, n}], 
    If[p != q, Prepend[If[v != {}, MergeF[a, v], a], {q, m}], 
     If[u != {}, Prepend[If[v != {}, MergeF[u, v], u], {p, n + m}], 
      If[v != {}, Prepend[v, {p, n + m}], {{p, n + m}}]]]]];
(*" test "*)
x = RandomInteger[r = {2, 2^50}]; y = RandomInteger[r]; 
MergeF[FactorInteger[x], FactorInteger[y]] == FactorInteger[x*y]
(*True*)
```

but it has a number of functional issues:

- It only merges two factorizations, not more separated by commas (or a list of factorizations, I'm ready to change the input format)
- When one input contains a pair matching `{-1,_}` or `{1,_}` (as occurs when factoring negative numbers or `1`), there can be unwanted terms of the form `{-1,_}` or `{1,_}` in the output
- It does not handle empty inputs, which should behave as neutral.

And above all it's inelegant! One of the worst thing is the manual parsing of the arguments. I vaguely see that I could break my definition into multiple ones like `MergeF[{{p_,n_}},{{q_,m_}}]:=…`, `MergeF[{{p_,n_},u_},{{q_,m_}}]:=…`, `MergeF[{{p_,n_}},{{q_,m_},v_}]:=…`, `MergeF[{{p_,n_},_u},{{q_,m_},v_}]:=…` but I'm not sure that's the way to go.

**How can I make a more general and elegant version?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MergeF[a___] :=
  Sort@KeyValueMap[List, GroupBy[Join[a], First -> Last, Total]] /.
    {{-1, _?EvenQ} -> Nothing, {-1, _?OddQ} -> {-1, 1}, {1, _} -> Nothing}

x = RandomInteger[r = {2, 2^50}]; y = RandomInteger[r];
MergeF[FactorInteger[x], FactorInteger[y]] == FactorInteger[x*y]
(*    True    *)

MergeF[]
(*    {}    *)

MergeF[FactorInteger[-123], FactorInteger[-456]]
(*    {{2, 3}, {3, 2}, {19, 1}, {41, 1}}    *)

MergeF[FactorInteger[1]]
(*    {}    *)

MergeF[FactorInteger[-1], FactorInteger[-1], FactorInteger[-1]]
(*    {{-1, 1}}    *)
```

Comment: I could not come by it, but it's so concise and clear that I understand how it works and can build on that. E.g. by changing Total to Max and trivial adjustment of the replacements, it computes the LCM instead of product. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you want

```
MergeFactorizations[factorizations___] := 
    {#[[1, 1]], (Plus @@ #)[[2]]} & /@ 
    Gather[Join[factorizations], First@#1 == First@#2 &] //. 
    {{a___, {1, 1}, b___} /; Length[{a, b}] > 0 :> {a, b}, {} :> {{1, 1}}, 
    {_, 0} :> Nothing, {x : 1 | -1, n_} :> {x, Mod[n, 2]}} // Sort
```

For example

```
facts = FactorInteger /@ {-101342, -10042346, 103751}
 
MergeFactorizations @@ facts
Times @@ Power @@@ %
Apply[Times, Apply[Power, facts, {2}], {0, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{2, 2}, {11, 1}, {29, 1}, {1987, 1}, {7907, 1}, 
>  {7, 1}, {83, 1}, {6449, 1}, {1337617, 1}, {17, 2}, {359, 1}}
>  
> 105588578400873332
> 105588578400873332
> ```

It works with an arbitrary number of factorizations, and for empty input it returns `{}`

```
MergeFactorizations[]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

It also handles edge cases with factorizations of `1` and `-1`

```
MergeFactorizations @@ FactorInteger /@ {1, 1, -1}
MergeFactorizations @@ FactorInteger /@ {1, -1, -1}
```

> ```
> {{-1, 1}}
> {{1, 1}}
> ```